# Timer onClick javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
  this.ItemId = function (ItemId) {
        var itemParameters = ItemId;

        //put a timer
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Menu/ChangeItemId',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(itemParameters),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: self.ChangeItemIdSuccess,
                error: errorFunc
            }, 5000);
        });
    };
```

The post request is done as soon as ItemId has finished executing, before posting the data to the server, I would like to delay it (by 5 seconds) in case the user clicks the button again, changing the ItemId in the process.

Comment: You're passing `5000` as a parameter to `$.ajax()` instead of `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a typo to me:

setTimeout's prototype: `setTimeout(function,milliseconds,lang)`

You **added** the 5000 param to the **ajax** method and **not** to the **setTimeout** method.

Here's the valid code:

```
  this.ItemId = function (ItemId) {
        var itemParameters = ItemId;

        //put a timer
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Menu/ChangeItemId',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(itemParameters),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: self.ChangeItemIdSuccess,
                error: errorFunc
            });
        }, 5000);
    };
```

[`Here's`](http://jsfiddle.net/3moLevsp/) a simple example of `setTimeout`.

Comment: Explain the typo? OP now has to compare the two codes to see what little thing you changed.

Comment: I'm waiting to hear back from the asker on whether that was a mistake only in his question, but typos are a close vote reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting what you exactly want to do, but if you want if user clicks on the button, the request will be called 5000 milisec after the second click instead of the first click. You should try this:-

```
this.ItemId = function (ItemId) {
    var itemParameters = ItemId, me = this;
    //put a timer
    me.doneTypingInterval = 5000;
   // Call every time
   me.delayExecute = function() {
         clearTimeout(me.typingTimer);
         me.typingTimer = setTimeout(me.request, me.doneTypingInterval);
         return true;
   };
   // do ajax
     me.request = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Menu/ChangeItemId',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(itemParameters),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: self.ChangeItemIdSuccess,
            error: errorFunc
        });
    };

};
```